# How to validate pub and priv GPG strings

Tags: go, gnupg

I have a public and private key that I receive as strings in Go and need to verify that they are valid keys. The [default crypto library](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29082#issuecomment-809621751) is deprecated (I tried it, and it doesn't work; I think my format is too new).

I know I have 2 valid keys are

1. They were recently generated and
2. They have been validated through other means

So, how does one actually validate GPG keys in Go? Do I need to deconstruct the key myself?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: shelling out to `gpg` is always an option

Comment: Means, I can't open/validate the keys

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto is not the default crypto library. There is one another one https://pkg.go.dev/crypto which is part of the stdlib. Thats the default one.